# How to transform numpy array into numpy array of tuples?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, tuples

In Python numpy if I have a numpy array `np.array([1,2,3])`. How can I transform that into a numpy array `[(1,1), (2,4), (3,9)]`?

Comment: What are the transformation requirements? I infer each tuple is basic multiplication; but the requirements must be explicitly stated. Additionally, what have you tried on *your own*?

Comment: do you really need a vector of tuples (i.e. object type)?

Comment: Specify the `shape` and `dtype` of the desired result.  Your display is ambiguous, looking more like a list of tuples, not an array.  The distinction between list and array is important!

Comment: Why not use a 2d array instead of 1d array of tuples?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```py
list(zip(a, a*a))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a naive approach but it still works.

```
lst = np.array([1,2,3])
array = []
for i in lst:
    array.append(tuple((i, i*i)))
dt=np.dtype('int,int')
arr = np.array(array,dtype=dt)
print(arr)
print(type(arr))
```

It will output NumPy array

```
[(1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9)]
```

Comment: For completeness, show `print(repr(arr))`

Comment: there can be some better approaches but this approach is for those who want to do everything with for loop :D

Answer (score 0):

Using comprehensions, and if na is any numpy array of integers (like the one in your example):

```
result = np.array( [(i, i*i) for i in na], dtype=[('a','<i4'),('b','<i4')] )
```